# Homeomorphism between $Y$ and $\{b\}\times Y$

Tags: general-topology, product-space

If I have two topological spaces $(X,\mathcal{T}_x)$ and $(Y,\mathcal{T}_y)$. I am trying to show that the space $\{b\}\times Y$ is homeomorphic to Y, where $b\in X$

It is my understanding that if I find a function between the two spaces:

$$T: \{b\}\times Y\longrightarrow  Y$$

that is continuous, bijective and $T^{-1}$ is also continuous then the two spaces are homeomorphic.

I figured that

$$T(b, y)=y$$

would suffice. I am self teaching myself topology. Is my function enough to justify that the two topological spaces are homeomorphic?

Comment: Yes, that function is a valid homeomorphism. But you need to prove it! Regarding notation, what does $\{b\}\times y$ mean? The domain $\{b\}\times Y$ consists of elements of the type $(b,y)$ with $y\in Y$. So your definition of $T$ should read $T(b,y)=y$.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, your $T$ is the restriction (to $\{b\} \times X_2$) of the second projection $\pi_2: X_1 \times X_2 \to X_2$, which is continuous by the definition of the product topology, and restrictions of continuous functions are still continuous.

Its inverse is $j: X_2 \to X_1 \times X_2$ defined by $j(x)=(b,x) \in \{b\} \times X_2$, which is continuous as $\pi_1 \circ j$ is constantly $b$ (so continuous) and $\pi_2 \circ j$ is the identity on $X_2$ (so continuous too), using the universal property of continuity of $X_1 \times X_2$. So $T$ is continuous with continuous inverse and so a homeomorphism.

Answer (score 0):

The open sets in $X \times Y$ are by definition unions of products $U \times V$ with $U$ open in $X$ and $V$ open in $Y$.

The open sets in $\{x\}\times Y$ are intersections of $\{x\}\times Y$ with these open sets.  That is they are unions of sets of the form:
$$ (\{x\}\times Y)\cap (U \times V)$$

Such a set will either be: $$(\{x\}\times V)$$ or empty depending on whether or not $x\in U$.  Such sets are closed under union so any open set in $X \times Y$ has the form $(\{x\}\times V)$, for some open set $V$ in $Y$.

Conversely all such sets are open in $\{x\}\times Y$:
$$ (\{x\}\times V)=(\{x\}\times Y)\cap (X \times V)$$

Thus under your identification the open sets of $Y$ and $\{x\}\times Y$ are the same.

Answer (score 0):

Indeed, $\{$x$\}$ $\times Y\approx Y$, where $x\in X$ and $X$ is a space.
Note that $X\times Y$ is assumed to be equipped with the product topology.

The map $T: \{x \} \times Y\rightarrow Y$ given by $T(x,y)=y$ is indeed a homeomorphism.

Let $\pi: X\times Y\rightarrow Y$ denote the projection map. Clearly, $\pi$ is $T$ when the domain is restricted to $ \{x \} \times Y$. As a consequence, continuity follows. The inverse of $T$ is $T^{-1}(y)=(x,y)$ . Since $\pi \circ T^{-1}$ (this is the restricted projection map) is the identity map on $Y$, it follows that $T^{-1}$ is continuous. Therefore we conclude that the two spaces are homeomorphic via the map $T$.